# Microsoft SQL page level restore, no valid backup. Confirming process

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, restore

We have a database in production that is coming up with issues after running DBCC CHECKDB. This particular DB was moved from a development environment to production. During this time, for some reason the corruption occurred. This DB is still in the development environment but does not have any issues. What I tried doing was setting both DB to full recovery mode, taking a full backup of the development version and trying to do a page level restore in production (in a test environment). It sees the bad pages in production but the backup isn't working, it is totally possible that the corruption is on data that isn't in the development environment.

Before I call this one and run the repair with data loss I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

```
Date and time: 2018-12-14 00:04:27
Command: DBCC CHECKDB ([DBNAME]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY Msg 8909, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 3659194856177664 (type Unknown), page ID (1:24021372) contains an incorrect page ID in its page header. The PageId in the page header = (0:4).
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data), page (1:24021371). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -1.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data): Page (1:24021371) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data): Page (1:24021372) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021371), slot 1, text ID 939689574400 is referenced by page (1:23834455), slot 67, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021371), slot 2, text ID 939692392448 is referenced by page (1:24021235), slot 7, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021371), slot 3, text ID 939693899776 is referenced by page (1:24021234), slot 12, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021371), slot 4, text ID 939695276032 is referenced by page (1:23834455), slot 84, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021371), slot 5, text ID 939714478080 is referenced by page (1:14929965), slot 13, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 0, text ID 939694555136 is referenced by page (1:24021234), slot 13, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 1, text ID 939700256768 is referenced by page (1:14920826), slot 17, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 3, text ID 939714412544 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 18, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 5, text ID 939714609152 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 22, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 7, text ID 939715461120 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 26, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 8, text ID 939716313088 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 27, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 9, text ID 939719327744 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 31, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 10, text ID 939722407936 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 45, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 11, text ID 939723915264 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 54, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8965, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24021372), slot 12, text ID 939729616896 is referenced by page (1:23860960), slot 75, but was not seen in the scan.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24023161), slot 5, text ID 939716313088 is not referenced.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24023163), slot 1, text ID 939719327744 is not referenced.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24023166), slot 0, text ID 939722407936 is not referenced.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24024057), slot 0, text ID 939723915264 is not referenced.
Msg 8964, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Table error: Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 71825501440245760 (type LOB data). The off-row data node at page (1:24024062), slot 0, text ID 939729616896 is not referenced.
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939689574400 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23834455:67)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939692392448 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23834455:75)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939693899776 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23834455:80)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939694555136 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23834455:82)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939695276032 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23834455:84)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939700256768 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:9)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939714412544 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:18)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939714478080 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:19)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939714609152 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:22)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939715461120 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:26)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939716313088 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:27)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939719327744 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:31)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939722407936 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:45)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939723915264 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:54)
Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 1 Object ID 753515305, index ID 1, partition ID 330857355739136, alloc unit ID 330857355739136 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 939729616896 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:23860960:75) CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 38 consistency errors in table 'TABLENAME' (object ID 753515305).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 39 consistency errors in database 'DBNAME'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DBNAME).
Outcome: Failed
Duration: 00:32:08
Date and time: 2018-12-14 00:36:35
```

Comment: I'd call Microsoft before you run that. Personally I'd never run it if i could avoid it but that's me. I'd restore from backup. What's the ouput of the DBCC command? If the corruption is on an index, you can simply drop it and recreate it often. You say that the DB in dev is still good, why not redo your backup and restore? [Here's a good starting point](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/)

Comment: Copy the errors from the DBCC output in your question so we can determine what is the issue. Try backing up your database using an alternative to what you are using (Wizard or T-SQL). In the Media/Backup options enable the Verify backup when finished and copy any errors here. Ensure that the backup file has been completely transferred from your development to production. Also in my opinion do not restore development databases to production because you may have data integrity issues. Apply all updates (dacpacs/updates/etc) to prod after successfully testing in your development environ.

Comment: Restore pages has many restrictions and limitations. Hopefully you are not encountering one of those. [Restore Pages (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: 1) How was it moved from dev to prod? 2) What is the risk of backing up and restoring it again?